# With Linux policy routing, from and to together misbehave

Tags: linux, routing, iproute2

I have the following IP configuration (some output omitted):

```
# ip ad sh
1: lo: 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0:
    inet 11.224.79.54/28 brd 11.224.79.63 scope global eth0
3: eth1: 
    inet 11.224.79.4/28 brd 11.224.79.15 scope global eth1
```

```
# ip ru sh
0:  from all lookup local
666:    from 11.224.79.54 to 52.219.72.0/22 iif lo lookup 1
```

```
# ip ro sh tab 1
default via 11.224.79.49 dev eth0
11.224.79.48/28 dev eth0 scope link
```

And when trying to ping some address from the `to` range of rule `666`, I get:

```
# ping 52.219.74.137
connect: Network is unreachable
```

When I do `ping -I eth0`, it works:

```
# ping -I eth0 52.219.74.137
PING 52.219.74.137 (52.219.74.137) from 11.224.79.54 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 52.219.74.137 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 999ms
```

(icmp is blocked, but that's expected)

Anyway, when I modify the rule `666` to:

```
[root@ip-11-224-79-54 centos]# ip ru sh
0:  from all lookup local
666:    from all to 52.219.72.0/22 iif lo lookup 1
```

the `ping` perfectly works even without `-I eth0`, and `tcpdump` shows `11.224.79.54` as the source IP of the packet.

In the first case, pinging with SRC IP of eth1 should not work as well, but it does:

```
# ping -I eth1 52.219.74.137
PING 52.219.74.137 (52.219.74.137) from 11.224.79.4 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
```

(should in my opinion be `connect: Network is unreachable`)

What am I doing wrong? It just does not make any sense to me.

Comment: I think you should at least show the main table as well and not omit any rules (and show the tables they look up).

Comment: @TomYan main routing table is not used. I can show other rules but it's all unrelated

Answer (score 1):

"Source IP address" is not the same thing as "source interface". The ping ICMP packets were still generated locally in all cases – they were *not* actually received via eth0 nor eth1, they merely used those interfaces' addresses.

These outgoing packets technically don't *have* an input interface, but the Linux kernel considers all locally generated traffic to come from 'lo' (LOOPBACK_IFINDEX) for rule matching purposes.

(Probably unrelated, but the source code also has a comment: "[...] We are allowed to send packets with saddr of another iface.")

Comment: Sure the packets were generated locally, but I'm trying to route packets originated from one local IP to be routed via this rule, and packet from another local IP not to be routable. This obviously can't be done using `iif` or `oif`, as all locally generated packets have `iif lo` (as seen in man ip-rule). So what is the value of `from` at the moment when `connect()` is called?

Comment: `man 3 connect` suggests that _If the socket has not already been bound to a local address, connect() shall bind it to an address which, unless the socket's address family is AF_UNIX, is an unused local address._ Any clue what is the _unused local address_?

Comment: When you're using a TCP or UDP socket – where the socket "addresses" are (ip_addr, port) combinations – then the quote also refers to an unused (ip_addr, port) combination. First the kernel uses some algorithm to choose the best local IP address (RTA_PREFSRC, RFC 3484, same interface, etc.), then it chooses a "free" local port.

Comment: If the program did not explicitly `bind()` to a local address, then I have a suspicion the rules are processed twice: first to find a matching route and get its RTA_PREFSRC attribute if any ("src ..." in iproute2), selecting a local address this way, then again to find a matching route for actual packet delivery once the source IP address has been chosen.